# Unable to write Excel File using Apache POI on server

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

I am using Apache POI 4.1.0 to create an excel file from java code on particular location.
When I run it on local machine file get generated in a fine way but when I create WAR and upload on server to do same operation of creating excel file it throws an exception as below,

```
2020-02-28 12:19:58,309 ERROR (com.credentek.recon.threadReportGeneration.ProductLevelReportsGeneration:1454) - Exception : 
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: OOXML file structure broken/invalid - core document '/xl/workbook.xml' not found.
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.getPartFromOPCPackage(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:743)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<init>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:148)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<init>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:138)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.<init>(POIXMLDocument.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:276)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:198)
    at com.credentek.recon.threadReportGeneration.ProductLevelReportsGeneration.PrepareBRSStatementSheet(ProductLevelReportsGeneration.java:1327)
    at com.credentek.recon.threadReportGeneration.ProductLevelReportsGeneration.GenerateProductLevelReports(ProductLevelReportsGeneration.java:213)
    at com.credentek.recon.main.ReportGenerationSchedular.ExecuteReport(ReportGenerationSchedular.java:126)
    at com.credentek.recon.main.ReportGenerationSchedular.ReportGenerationSheduler(ReportGenerationSchedular.java:69)
    at com.credentek.recon.main.Main$1.run(Main.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**My Code for generating excel file is as below**

```
private void PrepareBRSStatementSheet(String p_fileName, String p_sheetName, String p_productName, String p_asOnDate, String p_preparedBy, 
            String p_checkedBy, String p_reviewedBy, String p_desclaimer)  throws Exception {

        log.info(p_sheetName + " Sheet writting started");

        File l_file = null;
        OutputStream l_fos = null;

        XSSFWorkbook l_workbook = null;
        XSSFSheet l_sheet = null;
        XSSFRow l_row = null;

        int l_rowCount = 0;

        double l_crByBankNotByUs = 0.0;
        double l_crByUsNotByBank = 0.0;
        double l_drByBankNotByUs = 0.0;
        double l_drByUsNotByBank = 0.0;
        double l_difference = 0.0;
        double l_closingBookBalanceTotal = 0.0;
        double l_closingBankBalanceTotal = 0.0;

        try {

            // ---------Fetching values to print in report from JSON object
            l_crByUsNotByBank = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(brsStatementJson.opt("j_crByUsNotByBank").toString()));
            l_drByUsNotByBank = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(brsStatementJson.opt("j_drByUsNotByBank").toString()));
            l_crByBankNotByUs = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(brsStatementJson.opt("j_crByBankNotByUs").toString()));
            l_drByBankNotByUs = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(brsStatementJson.opt("j_drByBankNotByUs").toString()));
            l_closingBookBalanceTotal = Double.parseDouble(brsStatementJson.opt("j_closingBookBalanceTotal").toString()) * -1;
            l_closingBankBalanceTotal = Double.parseDouble(brsStatementJson.opt("j_closingBankBalanceTotal").toString());

            // ---------Calculating diff value according to formula
            l_difference = l_closingBankBalanceTotal - l_crByBankNotByUs - l_crByUsNotByBank + l_drByBankNotByUs + l_drByUsNotByBank - l_closingBookBalanceTotal;

            log.info(l_difference +"="+ l_closingBankBalanceTotal +"-"+ l_crByBankNotByUs +"-"+ l_crByUsNotByBank +"+"+ l_drByBankNotByUs +"+"+ l_drByUsNotByBank +"-"+ l_closingBookBalanceTotal);

            l_file = new File(p_fileName);

            if (l_file.exists()) {
                l_workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(l_file));
            } else {
                l_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            }

            //--------Diff Cell Style creation started
            Font l_boldFont = l_workbook.createFont();
            l_boldFont.setBold(true);
            l_boldFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);

            XSSFCellStyle l_disclaimerStyle = l_workbook.createCellStyle();
            l_disclaimerStyle.getWrapText();

            XSSFCellStyle l_leftDataStyle = l_workbook.createCellStyle();
            l_leftDataStyle.setFont(l_boldFont);
            l_leftDataStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_leftDataStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_leftDataStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_leftDataStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);

            XSSFCellStyle l_rightDataStyle = l_workbook.createCellStyle();
            l_rightDataStyle.setFont(l_boldFont);
            l_rightDataStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_rightDataStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_rightDataStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_rightDataStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);

            XSSFCellStyle l_topHeaderStyle = l_workbook.createCellStyle();
            l_topHeaderStyle.setFont(l_boldFont);
            l_topHeaderStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            l_topHeaderStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_topHeaderStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_topHeaderStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_topHeaderStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);

            byte[] l_middleHeaderColor = { (byte) 183, (byte) 222, (byte) 232 };
            XSSFCellStyle l_middleHeaderStyle = l_workbook.createCellStyle();
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(l_middleHeaderColor, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setFont(l_boldFont);
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_middleHeaderStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);

            byte[] l_lowerHeaderColor = { (byte) 252, (byte) 213, (byte) 181 };
            XSSFCellStyle l_lowerHeaderStyle = l_workbook.createCellStyle();
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(l_lowerHeaderColor, new DefaultIndexedColorMap()));
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setFont(l_boldFont);
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
            l_lowerHeaderStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
            // --------Diff Cell Style creation ended

            // ---------Report data plotting started
            l_sheet = l_workbook.createSheet(p_sheetName);

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(++l_rowCount);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_topHeaderStyle, "L&T Finance Limited - " + p_productName + " (No of Accounts: " + (totalAccountCount) + ")");
            l_sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(l_rowCount, l_rowCount, 1, 2));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(++l_rowCount);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_middleHeaderStyle, "Bank Reconciliation Statement as on " + Utils.convertDateFormats(p_asOnDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd MMM yyyy"));
            l_sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(l_rowCount, l_rowCount, 1, 2));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(++l_rowCount);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_lowerHeaderStyle, "Details");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_lowerHeaderStyle, "Amount (Rs)");

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "A. Closing Balance as per Bank Statement");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_closingBankBalanceTotal));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "B. Credit by Bank & Not By Us - Cash Deposit /Cheque Collection");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_crByBankNotByUs));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "C. Credit By Us & Not By Bank  - Book Reversal");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_crByUsNotByBank));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "D. Debit by Bank & Not By Us - Cheque Return / Charges");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_drByBankNotByUs));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "E. Debit By Us & Not By Bank  - Cheque Deposited");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_drByUsNotByBank));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "F. Closing Balance As per Bank Book");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_closingBookBalanceTotal));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, l_leftDataStyle, "Difference  = A - B-C + D+E - F = 0");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_rightDataStyle, String.format("%.2f", l_difference));

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(l_rowCount += 2);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, null, "Prepared By");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, null, p_preparedBy);

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(++l_rowCount);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, null, "Checked  By");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, null, p_checkedBy);

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(++l_rowCount);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, null, "Reviewed By");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, null, p_reviewedBy);

            l_row = l_sheet.createRow(++l_rowCount);
            AddCell(l_row, 1, null, "Disclaimer");
            AddCell(l_row, 2, l_disclaimerStyle, p_desclaimer);
            // ---------Report data plotting ended

            // ---------Expanding Columns to fit to data.
            l_sheet.autoSizeColumn(1, true);
            l_sheet.autoSizeColumn(2, true);

            l_fos = new FileOutputStream(l_file);
            l_workbook.write(l_fos);
            l_fos.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception : ",e);
        } catch (Throwable tw) {
            log.error("Throwable : ",tw);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (l_fos != null) {
                    l_fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("IOException : ",e);
            }
            try {
                if (l_workbook != null) {
                    l_workbook.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("IOException : ",e);          
            }

        }

        log.info(p_sheetName + " Sheet writting ended");

    }
```

Comment: Your file probably doesn't exist or is not an excel file

Comment: Are you sure that your file is an excel file and that your program can acces to it ?

Comment: @Fizik26 Yes I am creating .xlsx file, and file is also get created but it is unable to write in that file

Comment: If you set the authorization for this file to be execute / write and read by everyone, it's the same error ? ( I don't know if you are on windows or Linux )